# Solspace Calendar Orderby Date vs. Title

Tags: solspace-calendar, orderby

If I want to output the same list of occurrences by date vs. by title, is the best way to do this by switching tags?  So for by date, use {exp:calendar:cal}, but for by title, use {exp:calendar:occurrences}?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use `{exp:calendar:cal}` for ordering by **date** (it's the only tag that truly orders events and its occurrences in chronological order), and `{exp:calendar:events}` (or `{exp:calendar:occurrences}` if you need occurrences of each of those event entries) if you want to order by something else such as **title**.